# Count how many times a variable appears in an array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm counting how many times something appears in an array stored in a session:

```
session_start();

//product IDNO
$product_idno = isset($_POST['product_idno']) ? $_POST['product_idno'] : ""; 
// Product Qauntity
$product_qauntity = isset($_POST['product_qauntity']) ? $_POST['product_qauntity'] : "";
// Product Supplier
$product_supplier = isset($_POST['product_supplier']) ? $_POST['product_supplier'] : ""; 


$session_array = $_SESSION['portal_quote'][$product_idno] 
   = array(
       'product_qauntity' => $product_qauntity, 
       'product_supplier' => $product_supplier
   );
```

How can I count how many times a supplier appears in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how many times `$_SESSION['portal_quote'][i]['product_supplier']` of specified literal occurs in that structure?

You can treat an array stored in `$_SESSION` **like any other array** in PHP, so e.g.:

```
$supplier= "Bob"; //the supplier you are looking for
$occurences = 0;

$arr = $_SESSION['portal_quote'];
foreach($arr as $record){
    if($record['product_supplier'] == $supplier){
        $occurences++;
    }
}

echo "Supplier ".$supplier." occured ".$occurences." times.";
```

Comment: thank you so much i have been trying to work that our for hours, your an absolute legend in my books :-) thank you for the fast response also

Comment: @Nathan No problem. Be more careful in future (check what are you writing twice before you publish it).

Comment: @PolGraphic I've edited your answer to remove the extraneous content (which is better suited as a comment to the original question).

Comment: @admdrew I don't see a problem with it, don't worry ;)